# WebClient error in reading rss feeds

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, rss, windows-store-apps, webclient

I am trying to read live rss feeds from a website.
The following code is being used by me.

```
public static List<RssNews> Read(string url)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();//error line

    string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(result);
    return (from descendant in document.Descendants("item")
    select new RssNews()
        {
            Description = descendant.Element("description").Value,
            Title = descendant.Element("title").Value,
            PublicationDate = descendant.Element("pubDate").Value
            }).ToList();
        }
```

The error i am getting is:

> The type or Namespace Name could not be found.

Please Help!

Comment: Please post the full error and stack trace.

Comment: Full Error is:Error 1 The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Arran - what do you mean by Stack Trace?

Answer (score 0):

`WebClient` is not supported in Windows Store Apps.  Use the [HTTPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) instead.

For more information on what is and is not supported in Windows Store apps see the [.NET for Windows Store apps overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you! john . could you also specify as to how much the coding will change if we use HTTPCLIENT?